# Scanning each HTML node with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How can we scan each element and sub-element of an HTML document with Nokogiri, and testing for each one if the current tag is a block?

According to http://wiki.github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/examples, we can test if an element is a block using:

```
element[:class] == "block"
```

But I don't see how to scan and test each HTML ones...

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘is a block’? Are you talking about the ‘block elements’ (as in http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#block)? If so I think you'd just have to check for each known tagname.

Comment: Yes, each block elements: div, p, h1, h2, etc. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very useful `traverse` function lets you iterate through every element of the document. [See the doc.](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#M000308)